# Logging onto computer user accounts

Tags: networking, user-accounts, login, connection-sharing

By my request our school IT set up a basic admin account on my computer. I have the username and password but I am unable to log on because I am always prompted to log onto on of the network accounts. How can I log onto one of the computer accounts?

Comment: What version of Windows is this? Are these machines Networked based and you want to access the local user?

Comment: Windows 7 any yes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the logon window, which you should as the machine makes use of network accounts, you will need to login as the following:

COMPUTERNAME\Adminname

The first part designates the DOMAIN, in this case, the local computer.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I determine the computername? Is it just "LocalComputer"?

Comment: dont need the computername just replace it with a dot: .\Adminname